# Adding row to data frame while maintaining the class of each column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a row to a data frame showing column totals.

```
test = data.frame('name' = c('a','b','c'),'x' = c(1,2,3),'y' = c(1,2,3))
class(test[,2])
[1] "numeric"

test = rbind(test,c('Total',apply(test[,-1],2,sum)))
   name x y
1     a 1 1
2     b 2 2
3     c 3 3
4 Total 6 6

class(test[,2])
[1] "character"
```

I need the number columns to remain numeric.
I understand this happens because the mixed vector I am trying to add is actually a character vector.  What is a good way around this?  I tried rbind with a list but it didn't work with the apply function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need that row to be a three element list with the proper names. Furthermore, your first column is a factor vector, so you either need to deal with that or not make it a factor:

```
test = data.frame('name' = c('a','b','c'),
 'x' = c(1,2,3),
 'y' = c(1,2,3),
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 test = rbind(test,c(name='Total',as.list(apply(test[,-1],2,sum))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it your way then just change those columns back to numeric.

```
test[,2:3] <- sapply(test[,2:3], as.numeric)
```